# If X then look for Y in same row (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sample spreadsheet

[image]

Looking to find out how many times each name appears in right 4 columns depending on the W/L column.  Example output I am looking for is a count of times `Mozzie` appears in any of the four right side columns where there is a W in the W/L Column

Comment: Not clear. So, what would be output for your data?

Comment: Added actually spread sheet and gave more info on output I am looking for.

Comment: Multiple countifs or a single Sumproduct will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula. Adjust ranges for you sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B16="W")*(E3:F16="Mozzie"))
```

[image]